# creating XML file with LINQ to XML

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I need to write linq to xml query of such kind of below xml data

```
<PRODUCT>
<ID>34169</ID>
<D1>good</D1>
<D2>well</D2>
<L1>lame</L1>
<L2>killer</L2>
<BR>IOMEGA</BR>
<KDV>18</KDV>
<IMG>34169.JPG</IMG>
<EAN>data1</EAN>
<ATP>50+</ATP>
<DM3>0,51</DM3>
<S>
  <L>Tip</L>
  <V>HARICI</V>
</S>
<S>
  <L>Renk</L>
  <V>METALIK GRI</V>
</S>
<S>
  <L>Kapasite (GB)</L>
  <V>500</V>
</S>
<S>
  <L>Dönüş Hızı (Rpm)</L>
  <V>5400,0</V>
</S>
<S>
  <L>Arabirim</L>
  <V>USB 2.0</V>
</S>
<S>
  <L>Form Faktörü (Inch)</L>
  <V>2,5</V>
</S>
<S>
  <L>Ön Bellek (Kb/mb)</L>
  <V>8,0</V>
</S>
<S>
  <L>Satış Garanti Süresi (ay)</L>
  <V>36</V>
</S>
```

my problems are

1. get only the first image when there
   is several images in the
   database(img holds the path of an
   image as a string in my database
   table)
2. handle the `<S>` part

I am new to LINQ to XML please help, thanks.

Comment: not sure I know what exactly you mean. Saying e.g. what you want to retrieve from the above xml would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is my answer

```
 XElement productCatalog = 
                   new XElement("PRODUCTCATALOG",

                               from urun in db.TBLP1URUNs
                               select new XElement("PRODUCT",

                                           new XElement("ID", urun.ID),

                                           new XElement("D1", urun.MODEL),

                                           new XElement("D2", urun.URUNACIKLAMA),

                                           new XElement("L1", urun.TBLP1URUNKATEGORI.TREENAME),

                                           new XElement("IMG", db.TBLP1URUNRESIMs.Where(p => p.URUN_ID == urun.ID).First().FILE_NAME),

                                           new XElement("EAN", urun.STOKKODU),

                                           new XElement("ATP", GetUrunStokById(urun.ID)),//STOKMIKTARI

                                           new XElement("DM3", urun.DESI),

                                           from ozellikler in urun.TBLP1OZELLIK_URUNs
                                           select new XElement("S",

                                               new XElement("L", ozellikler.TBLP1OZELLIK.TBLP1OZELLIKTIPI.TIPI),

                                               new XElement("V", ozellikler.TBLP1OZELLIK.OZELLIK))

                                               )                           
                            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps..

```
        var productElement = XDocument.Load("product.xml").Root;

        var firstImagePath  = productElement.Element("IMG").Value;
        var sElements = productElement.Elements("S");

        //if you want an object instead of XElements, you can do
        var sElementObjects = sElements.Select(xe => new
                                        {
                                              L = xe.Element("L").Value,
                                              V = xe.Element("V").Value,
                                         });
```

Comment: maybe i asked the question in a wrong way, I want to create an XML doc like the one in my question, and i am taking data from my database.And I am ok with id, d1,d2, etc. but at the S part it is one more level deeper and I cant  make it look like this what i am able to do is showing the same product for every S tag. I think I need some kind of X node or somthing which can contain another xelements