# How to insert xml node using linq2xml?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I know how to read, but can't find how to edit, also I want to ask how to insert ?

my xml file is looking like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataWorkers>
    <worker name="1" workshop="2" salary="25000"/>
    <worker name="3" workshop="4" salary="25000"/>
</dataWorkers>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XElement dataWorkers=  new XElement("worker", 
                                    new XAttribute("name", 1),

                                    new XAttribute("workshop", 2),

                                    new XAttribute("salary",25000)

//another way to add a worker to dataWorkers
XElement worker = new XElement("worker");
            XAttribute name = new XAttribute("name",1);
            XAttribute workshop = new XAttribute("workshop",4);
            XAttribute salary = new XAttribute("salary",25000);
            worker.Add(name);
            worker.Add(workshop);
            worker.Add(salary);
dataWorkers.Add(worker);

XDocument myXml= new XDocument( new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "true"),
                                new XElement(dataWorkers));
```

For better understanding check [LINQ to XML - 5 Minute Overview](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx) and [Understanding C#: Simple LINQ to XML examples (tutorial)](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/10/understanding-c-simple-linq-to.html)

Comment: @nCdy you can also take a look at this [creating XML file with LINQ to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632747/creating-xml-file-with-linq-to-xml) for much complicated ones

Answer (score 2):

First Load the xml doc

```
XElement el = XElement.Load(@"yourfile.xml");
```

Then use the **SetElementValue** and add the records and finally save it

```
elem.SetElementValue("2","5", "150000");
el.Save("yourfile.xml");
```

SetElementValue will create the element if not present else would update the existing element

Answer (score 1):

Insert :

```
XElement.Add (new XElement("el"));
```

Edit:

```
var el = xDocument.Root.Elements("worker").First();
el.Attribute ("name").SetValue ("name1");
xDocument.Save();
```